# What do nth prime of a number mean?

Tags: java

> Given an input n, find out the nth prime?

**MyApproach**

What I understood

For Example,

For number 2 its nth position is 1

For number 3 its nth position is 2  // For this input I get Expected output 5.

For number 5 its nth position is 3

```
public int computePrime(int n)
{
    int c=0;
    boolean b=isPrime(n);
    if((b==true))
    {
        c++;
    }
    return c;

    //write your code here

}
public boolean isPrime(int n)
{

    for(int i=2;i<=n/2;)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            i++;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

For Input

```
Parameters  Actual Output   Expected Output
'3'          1               5
```

> ## My Qn is Can anyone guide me what the statement mean.Am I correct in understanding the problem.I am not asking you to code for me.I will do it

Comment: Ever heard of google?

Comment: All I am getting is code code and code.I want to understand what the problem means?

Comment: You're supposed to return the *nth prime number (counting 2 as the first)*. Not the position of "n".

Comment: Well you want to find the nth prime number.  primes=1,2,3,5,7,11,... or a number that can be divided(evenly) by it's self and one.  Note this is a forum for code questions.

Comment: @zapl can you give me example what you mean?

Comment: For parameter `n=3` you're supposed to return the 3rd prime number that exists. "2" is the first, then there is "3", then "5". So 5 is the 3rd prime and your result. The algorithm needs to find prime numbers until it has found enough, then return that prime number,

Comment: zapl Thanku I will code it now

Comment: @cliff2310 I know Sir this is a code forum.I also understood where I was wrong.But I need to understand the statement to write the code.Otherwise I would waste my time as well yours.

Answer (score 0):

You want to return the nth prime number, where "n" is the input given, so what you want is something like this:

```
boolean isPrime(int i)
{
    int j = 1;
    while (j <= (i/2))
    {
        if (i%j == 0)
        {
            if (j!=1)
                return false;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return true;

}

void main(int n){

    int i = 0;
    int numbers = 2;
    while (i<n){
        if (isPrime(number)){
            i++;
        }
        numbers++;
    }
    return numbers;

}
```